# Rust - Cannot Access r2d2 pool connection from Rocket State

Tags: rust, rust-diesel, rust-rocket, r2d2

I am currently learning Rust and Rocket

Using Rust 1.54.0+Rocket 0.5.0_rc1+ Diesel 1.4.7 + r2d2 0.8.9

I created a DB Postgres connection pool with r2d2. I want to share the connection pool between requests/Routes, to do that I am trying to use Rocket Managed State. https://rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/guide/state/#managed-state

I created a DB Connection Pool, saved it on the state, but when I tried to access that DB Connection Pool from the Route. I am getting 2 error on the same line

`Cell<i32> cannot be shared between threads safely`

`RefCell<HashMap<StatementCacheKey<Pg>, pg::connection::stmt::Statement>> cannot be shared between threads safely`

here my code

```
pub async fn establish_pooled_connection() -> Result<PooledConnection<ConnectionManager<PgConnection>>, r2d2_diesel::Error> {
    dotenv().ok();
    let database_url = env::var("DATABASE_URL")
        .expect("DATABASE_URL must be set");
    let manager = ConnectionManager::<PgConnection>::new(&database_url);
    let pool = r2d2::Pool::builder().build(manager).expect("Failed to create pool.");
    let conn = pool.clone().get().unwrap();
    Ok(conn)
}

struct DBPool{
    db_pool: PooledConnection<ConnectionManager<PgConnection>>
}

#[rocket::main]
async fn main() {
  
    let pool = establish_pooled_connection();    
    rocket::build()
        .mount("/",routes![callapi])
        .manage(DBPool{db_pool: pool})
        .launch()
        .await.ok();       
}

#[post("/callapi", data = "<request>")]
async fn callapi(request: RequestAPI<'_>, _dbpool: &State<DBPool>) -> Json<models::api_response::ApiResponse> {
......
```

The errors are for this parameter

> `_dbpool: &State<DBPool>`

thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. In particular what is `State`? Also edit your question to add the _full_ error message, including context and the suggestions made by the compiler.

Comment: @Jmb I have updated the question, with more details, please let me know if you have any questions, thanks

Comment: Please include the _complete_ error message, it should start with something like: "error[E0277]: `Cell<i32>` cannot be shared between threads safely" and finish with: "error: aborting due to previous error". Please _include all the lines in between_, they are important for us to understand where the error comes from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I was able to make this work.

I mostly used this GitHub repo as base
https://github.com/practical-rust-web-development/mystore/tree/v1.1
The repo uses Actix but I am using Rocket.

I think my main miss understanding is that the base PostgreSQL connection is a PGConnection and what you get from the Pool is a PGPooledConnection which at the end is the same.

Here my code

db_connection.rs

```
use diesel::pg::PgConnection;
use dotenv::dotenv;
use std::env;
use diesel::r2d2::{ Pool, PooledConnection, ConnectionManager, PoolError };

pub type PgPool = Pool<ConnectionManager<PgConnection>>;
pub type PgPooledConnection = PooledConnection<ConnectionManager<PgConnection>>;

//Connects to Postgres and call init pool
pub fn establish_connection() -> PgPool {
    dotenv().ok();

    let database_url = env::var("DATABASE_URL")
        .expect("DATABASE_URL must be set");
    init_pool(&database_url).expect("Failed to create pool")
}


//Creates a default R2D2 Postgres DB Pool
fn init_pool(database_url: &str) -> Result<PgPool, PoolError> {
    let manager = ConnectionManager::<PgConnection>::new(database_url);
    Pool::builder().build(manager)
}


//this functions returns a connection from the Pool
pub fn pg_pool_handler(pool: &PgPool) -> Result<PgPooledConnection, PoolError> {
    let _pool = pool.get().unwrap();
    Ok(_pool)
}
```

main.rs

```
mod db_connection;
use db_connection::{PgPool};

#[rocket::main]
async fn main() {
    rocket::build()
        .mount("/API",routes![demo])
        .manage(db_connection::establish_connection()) //here is where you pass the pool to Rocket state.
        .launch()
        .await.ok();       
}

#[post("/demo", data = "<request>")]
async fn demo _dbpool: &State<PgPool>) -> Json<models::Response> {

let connection = db_connection::pg_pool_handler(_dbpool).unwrap();

let results = users.limit(1)
        .load::<User>(&connection)
        .expect("Error loading users");
........
```

That is the basic code, the code can be improved to handle errors in a better way.